# Which of the Ledas has impersonated another Leda?

Tags: orphan-black

*Orphan Black* has many impersonations among the sisters, beginning of course with Sarah stepping into Beth's shoes; there's also

- Sarah as Katja, to retrieve the briefcase (s1e2)
- Helena as Beth, at the police station
- Alison as Sarah, for Siobhan (s1e4)
- Sarah as Alison, at the house party (s1e6)
- Helena as Sarah, to meet their host mother (s1e10)
- Sarah as Cosima, at a Dyad reception (s2e1)
- Sarah as Rachel, to get into her apartment (s2e4)
- Sarah as Alison (unintentionally) at rehab (s2e7)
- Rachel as Sarah, to snatch Kira (s2e9)
- Sarah and Alison as Rachel and Sarah, to bluff Ferdinand (s3e1)
- Cosima as Alison (unintentionally) at the election event (s3e7)
- Krystal as Rachel, unwittingly (s3e8–10)
- Helena as Alison, at least four times so far

I don't think anyone has impersonated Helena yet.
I omitted simple errors without intent to deceive, as when Vic first met Alison.

Have there been any more instances in which one clone has impersonated another?

Comment: Barring "mistaken identity" swaps you're still missing these ones: Helena as Sarah at Club Neolution (1x07), Sarah as Alison / Sarah as Alison as Donnie (2x07), Sarah as MK (4x02)

Comment: Thanks, Will, I added the latter; the raid on Club Neo is a grey area imho.

Comment: Tempted to VTC as this is an on-going show and this list will inherently be incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

### Sarah

- **Beth**, for stealing her money and nosing around in police business (each of s1e1-5, s1e8, s1e9, s3e2, s3e3, s4e3, s4e9)
- **Katja**, to retrieve the briefcase (s1e2)
- **Alison**

  - at the house party (s1e6)
  - at rehab (unintentionally) (s2e7)
- **Helena**, when escaping from club Neolution (s1e7)
- **Cosima**, at a Dyad reception (s2e1)
- **Rachel**

  - to get into her apartment (s2e4)
  - to get information from Ferdinand (s3e1)
  - (s5e2)
  - to fool Westmorland (s5e9)
- **Krystal** (s4e10)
- **MK** (s4e2)

---

### Beth

Beth's corpse is identified as Sarah's (s1e1)

---

### Helena

- **Beth**, at the police station (s1e4)
- **Sarah**

  - when escaping from club Neolution (s1e7)
  - to meet their host mother (s1e10)
- **Alison**

  - to deal with Portuguese mob (s3e9)
  - to use Alison's health insurance (s4e2)
  - talking to detectives Collier and Linstein/Lindstein (credited twice with different names) about triple homicide from s3e9 (s4e3)

---

### Alison

- **Sarah**

  - for Siobhan (s1e4)
  - when fooling Ferdinand, while Sarah is imitating Rachel (s3e1)
  - as Hestia, at Felix' show opening (s5e8)

---

### Rachel

- **Sarah**, to snatch Kira (s2e9)
- **Krystal** (off-screen) (s3e8–10)

---

### Cosima

- **Alison** (unintentionally) at the election event (s3e7)
- **Sarah** as Metis, at Felix' show opening (s5e8)

---

### Krystal

As **Rachel**, unwittingly

---

### MK

As **Sarah** as **Rachel** (s5e2)

Comment: Made a CW for people to add to instead of having a bunch of partial answers.

Comment: Sarah as Krystal in s5e6 is probably not major enough to make this list, and I'm also not sure about the "personas" in tonight's episode (s5e8) - perhaps something like "Cosima as Sarah as [Metis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metis_(mythology))."